# How to record the changing cells using change event in VBA language?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm coding in VBA using change event to record every time the number is changing on the excel spreadsheet.

The changing numbers should be recorded from the beginning of the list and the list goes on and on.This is what i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

you may create a new module and add a global variable, for example.

Global Record As String

and on the workbook add sheet change

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Record = "" Then
    Record = Sheet1.Range("a1").Value
Else
    Record = Record & "," & Sheet1.Range("a1").Value
End If
End Sub